# PHP MySQL query builder

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there are any PHP code, modules, plugins that would allow me to build my own MySQL queries. E.g. The query builder that phpMyAdmin uses lets you make queries using dropdown menus.

It has to be a builder that will be on a website not software or application!

Must be user friendly! visual etc

Comment: visually so it is easy to see for a user who wants to find out stuff : e.g. I want to find out how many people bought bananas

Comment: You should write that into your question. It sounds like you want one for you as a developer, not one for the public to use.

Comment: No i want one so my users can get data that is relevant for them to so they can make business decisions

Comment: +1 Good question. I actually want to add something like this to my client's admin pages. Also, I like the part where it's a +100 bounty but you only have 59 rep ;-)

Comment: If your goal to allow people who don't know SQL at all to write queries, I think you're on a fool's errand. SQL *is* the language that was created to allow non-programmers to write queries.

Comment: Why can't you integrate phpMyAdmin into your application?

Comment: @Karolis because PHPadmins libraries and non modular - believe me i tried

Comment: @JamWaffles Unless I understood wrong, it means he had 159 rep before he put the bounty, since bounty is substracted from reputation immediately.

Comment: @Kheldar - Oh I see. I've never given a bounty, so I don't know how things work - thanks for clearing things up.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "needs to be on a WEBSITE", you are asking for Javascript/Jquery and not PHP

You want this ::

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SQL_QUERY_BUILDER

Demo for above
http://ksistem.com/jquery/sqlbuilderdemo.htm

in the Iframe type of thing on that page, scroll down to see the menu to build new queries.

---

OR This (more detailed)

http://aspquerybuilder.net/default.aspx

---

and this might also help ::

http://sourceforge.net/projects/myquerybuilder/

Comment: Why would I use ASP when my system is being built using PHP and Codeigniter framework lol!

Comment: @sqlmole that ASP is for future reference, and the other two, the jquery one and myquerybuilder will work with PHP and codeigniter framework, and since its Javascript/Jquery it will pretty much work with anything else as well.

Comment: That ASP product is really nice, +1.

Comment: @Pheonix the sourceforge link is dead... anybody have a different link? +1 for aspquerybuilder that is really nice

Answer (score 2):

Try the following tools. These does the same work of PhpMyAdmin but no guarantee that they would satisfy your taste.

1.Adminer (formerly phpMinAdmin)
A full-featured MySQL management tool written in PHP. Does more or less everything phpMyAdmin however consist of a single file only that is ready to upload to your servers and connect to the DB.

2.Navicat
This, in my opinion, is the best MySQL client out there. It does everything you want from a very user friendly interface. However, it doesn’t come free. There is a small price tag to it but is well worth it!

3.Sequel Pro
One for the Mac users.

4.SQLWave

5.SQLyog

6.BlueSQL

---

Free web based DB management tool.

7.SQL Buddy

9.DBDesigner 4

10.SQLGate

11.HeidiSQL

Is this what you want?

Comment: Adminer is excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. GUI tool with ability to build custom queries. No setup or config hassle. All in a single PHP file!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any like that, but you could just use phpMyAdmin and copy the query that's generated?

Comment: Yes but then that would be fixed, and not dynamic for users who want different queries

Comment: If your program's licence is compatible with the GPL, you can just copy the one from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

@sqlmole, there is no such tool that will let you build a query such as how many people purchased bananas. You will have to develop such a system. However, apart from PHPMyAdmin, MySQL GUI Tools from MySQL itself and WebYog are some tools known to me which can some how help you create queries visually. I would also love to see alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What about this [jQuery based SQL Query Builder](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SQL_QUERY_BUILDER)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to take a look at SQLBuilder https://github.com/c9s/SQLBuilder

which is MIT licensed, and it can generate cross platform SQL queries (mostly) for you:

```php
use SQLBuilder\Universal\Query\SelectQuery;
use SQLBuilder\Driver\MySQLDriver;
use SQLBuilder\Driver\PgSQLDriver;
use SQLBuilder\Driver\SQLiteDriver;

$mysql = new MySQLDriver;
$args = new ArgumentArray;

$query = new SelectQuery;
$query->select(array('id', 'name', 'phone', 'address','confirmed'))
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->partitions('u1', 'u2', 'u3')
    ->where()
        ->is('confirmed', true)
        ->in('id', [1,2,3])
    ;
$query
    ->join('posts')
        ->as('p')
        ->on('p.user_id = u.id')
    ;
$query
    ->orderBy('rand()')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ;

$sql = $query->toSql($mysql, $args);

var_dump($sql);
var_dump($args);
```